# Alternating series of arithmetic function values

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

Some time ago I asked about alternating sums like
$\sum_{n\leq x}(-1)^n \phi(n)$ where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient
and the similar sum involving $\sigma(n)$ where $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}d.$ 
Certain sums of this form are of some interest e.g. 
A.Ivic (1) and M.Jutila (2,3) show the importance of the alternating sum $$\sum_{n\leq x}(-1)^n d(n)$$ 
in connection with the relation between the error term in the mean value formula for $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|^2$ 
and the error $\Delta(x)$ in Dirichlet's formula for the average order of the divisor-function $d(n)$. 
Using $\sigma(2n)=\sigma(2)\sigma(n)-\sigma(n/2)$ (n even) and $\sigma(2n)=\sigma(2)\sigma(n)$ (n odd) we get 
$$\sum_{n\leq 4x}(-1)^n \sigma(n)= -\sum_{n\leq 4x}\sigma(n)+6\sum_{n\leq 2x}\sigma(n)-4\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n).$$
Denoting $\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma(n)$ by $S(x)$ then $$S(x)=\zeta(2)x^2/2+xR(x),\quad R(x) =O(\log^{2/3}x).$$
So if our sum is denoted by $A(x)$, $$A(4x)=-S(4x)+6S(2x)-4S(x)\mbox{ so } A(x)=\zeta(2)x^2/8+xR'(x)$$ 
where $$R'(x)=-(R(x)-3R(x/2)+R(x/4))/4=O(\log^{2/3}x) (=O(\log x)).$$
Is it possible that a better result holds ?

What about $\Omega$-results ? 
We know $R(x)=\Omega(\log\log x)$. Doesn't a corresponding $\Omega$-result for $R'(x)$ hold?
Hardy and Wright Theory of numbers p.353 prove that an infinite sequence of $X$s exists 
such that $\sigma(X)>K.X\log\log X$, $K,K'$ etc absolute constants.
Suppose if possible $R'(x)=o(\log\log x)$. Then $$|R'(x)|<\epsilon \log\log x$$ 
for all $x >$ some $x_0(\epsilon)$ and arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. 
$$A(x)-A(x-1)=\pm \sigma(x)=K'x^2-K'(x-1)^2+x(R'(x)-R'(x-1))+R'(x-1)$$ with $K'=\zeta(2)/8$.
So $$\sigma(x) \leq \ 2K'x+K'^2+x(|R'(x)|+|R'(x-1)|)+O(\log x)$$
and $$\sigma(x)/x \leq |R'(x)|+|R'(x-1)|+O(1)$$ as $\log x<x$ if $x\gt 1$
Take $X_0$ to be the first $$X\gt \max(x0+1,\exp\exp (K/\epsilon)).$$ Then $$\sigma(x)\leq 3\epsilon x\log\log x$$ 
for $x\gt X_0$, a contradiction. Hence $R'(x)=\Omega(\log\log x)$.
What's wrong with this ?

1. Aleksandar Ivic, Uniform Distribution Theory 1(2006), 125-135.
2. M. Jutila, Riemann’s zeta-function and the divisor problem, Arkiv Mat. 21(1983), 75-96 and II, ibid. 31(1993), 61-70.
3. M. Jutila, On a formula of Atkinson, in “Coll. Math. Sci. Janos Bolyai 34, Topics in classical Number Theory, Budapest 1981”, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1984, pp. 807-823.

Comment: Apologies, novice handling of MathJax caused 2 erroneous factors 'x' in Para. 2 line 4.Should be loglog x only , not x loglogx

Comment: Very many thanks to YCor - just starting with mathematics Tex !

Comment: If you have multiple questions, it's better to separate them into individual posts for clarity. Regarding your $\Omega$ question, yes—indeed it's easy to see immediately, for any sequence $a_n$ and any continuous function $f$ and any increasing (say) function $g$, that if $a_n = \Omega(g(n))$ then $\sum_{n\le x} a_n - f(x) = \Omega(g(x))$: one simply considers real values of $x$ just below and just above an integer $n$ that represents a champion value of $|a_n|$. This is a simpler way to express the argument you gave.

Comment: Thanks to Greg Martin. Presumably his simplification would be relevant to Y.-F. S. Pétermann, "An Ω-theorem for an error term related to the sum-of-divisors function", Monatshefte für Mathematik 103:2 (1987), pp. 145-157.